# "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" with a the JSON file from the OpenWeatherMap API

Tags: python, json, python-requests, typeerror

I have a problem with an scraped json file from the Air Pollution API OpenWeatherMap.

When I try to navigate through the data with `aqi = air_data['list']['main']['aqi']`, I get the following error: *TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str*.

The full code is:

```
import requests

URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/air_pollution?lat=MY_LATITUDE&lon=MY_LONGITUDE&appid=MY_API_KEY"

air_data = requests.get(URL).json()

aqi = air_data['list']['main']['aqi']

print(aqi, 'AirQualityIndex')
```

The *air_data* formatted with pprint looks like this:

```
{'coord': {'lat': MY_LAT, 'lon': MY_LON},
'list': [{'components': {'co': 223.64,
                      'nh3': 0.28,
                      'no': 0,
                      'no2': 5.91,
                      'o3': 42.92,
                      'pm10': 2.14,
                      'pm2_5': 1.79,
                      'so2': 1.79},
       'dt': 1640822400,
       'main': {'aqi': 1}}]}
```

I don't understand why it is thinking that the 1 behind 'aqi' is a string. In my other code with the Weather API it works without any problems.

Comment: `air_data['list']` is a list.  So use something like `air_data['list'][0]` to access its elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```py
aqi = air_data['list']['main']['aqi']
```

use:

```py
aqi = air_data['list'][0]['main']['aqi']
```

You didn't notice there is a list here.